# How does V8 handle scopes when WebAPI is used

Tags: javascript, v8

I know JavaScript is single threaded non blocking, and hands things such as setTimeout() to the web api, but how does it handle scopes?

lets say there is a function like

```
function example()
{
  const x = 10
  setTimeout(() => { console.log(x) }), 100)
}

example()
```

How does it keep track of the variables in that scope? or do they not get deleted?

Comment: Are you asking how closures are implemented internally in v8? If so, I don't think this  is the place to get an answer.

Comment: V8 doesn't handle closures any different whether a web API is used or not.